# Cordova, Barcode scanner opens twice in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner, angularjs-ng-click

The problem does not appear using the simulator CordovaSim or Ionic View app, but only when the project is build for Android.
When the problem appear the barcode reader need to read the DATA_MATRIX code twice to return back to the app.

```
$cordova -v
5.2.0   

$cordova platform ls
android 4.1.1

$cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-barcodescanner 0.7.0 "BarcodeScanner"
```

Part of my config.xml:

```
    <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
    <param name="wp-package" value="BarcodeScanner" />
    <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-barcodescanner" />
</feature>
```

Controller of the barcode reader:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('ScanCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup) {
$scope.message = '';
$scope.click = function() {
    console.log("apertura scanner");
    $scope.message = '';
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {

            if(result.cancelled == false){
                if(result.format == "DATA_MATRIX"){
                    var jsonToSend = result.text;

                    validate(jsonToSend);
                } else {
                    console.log("formato codice a barre non riconosciuto");
                }
            }else{
                console.log("lettura annullata");
            }                       
        }, 
        function (error) {
            alert("Errore scansione: " + error);
        }
    );
}

$scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.message = '';
}

validate = function(textJSON){
    console.log(textJSON);
    $http.post('http://www.esempio.con', textJSON).
      then(function(response) {
         console.log("success");
         console.log(angular.toJson(response));
         $scope.data = response.data.response;
         //alert(response.data.response);

         if(response.data.response == true){
            showAlert(true);
             $scope.message = '<img src="img/success.png" alt="" /><p>non valida</p>';
         }else{
            showAlert(false);
             $scope.message = '<img src="img/error.png" alt="" /><p>non valida</p>';
         }

      }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = "errore " + response.status + " " +response.statusText;
          console.error(response.status);
          console.error(response.statusText);
      });
}

// An alert dialog
showAlert = function(response) {
    if(response == true){
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: "Risultato",
              templateUrl: 'templates/popupTrue.html',
              scope: $scope,
              cssClass: 'resultPopup',
              okText: 'Chiudi'
          });
    } else {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: "Risultato",
              templateUrl: 'templates/popupFalse.html',
              scope: $scope,
              cssClass: 'resultPopup',
              okText: 'Chiudi'
          });
    } 
  alertPopup.then(function(res) {
    console.log('alert mostrato');
  });
}
})
```

Part of view:

```
<ion-slide ng-controller="ScanCtrl">
             <div class="contenuto">
                   <h2>Scansione</h2>
                    <div>
                        <button style="border-radius:7px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;" class="button button-large icon-left ion-ios-barcode-outline" ng-click="click()">
                            Avvia Scansione
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-bind-html="message"></div>

                    <div style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-show="message.length!=0">
                        <button style="border-radius: 7px;margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;" class="button button-large icon-left ion-trash-b" ng-click="clear()">
                            Pulisci Risultato
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </ion-slide>
```

Comment: Can you check if the `$scope.click` function is called twice on the click event?

Comment: can you post whatever view your calling this from?

Comment: Yeah, I miss it. With a long tap of the button (button code added) the problem doesn't appear. To test the double call I tried to use an alert message at start of the click() function. With it the problem doesn't appear.
Obviously they are not solution, but can help a lot. thank you.

Comment: With the alert message the problema doesn't appear because it's blocking the execution: I think that the problem is related to a double click event fired when you "touch" the button.

Comment: @lifeisfoo The problem seems to be solved by using the parameter: data-tap-disabled="true". Long-tap doesn't works anymore but is ok. Try to understand why and if it can be a real solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of data-tap-disabled="true" which loses the UI touch effect, I got it working by using on-touch instead of ng-click. I don't know why though.

```
<button on-touch="click()">
    Avvia Scansione
</button>
```

Comment: This did the trick. With ```ng-click```, the action was triggered twice. Thanks